# How to deserialize single property response to C# Object?

Tags: c#, api, deserialization, long-integer

I am testing APIs and currently, I am testing a Post method that returns a Long data type Id.
I have created a C# object class, where I also have other properties that it will return from another API call. For now, this Post call only returns an Id and I want to Map it to the Id property in my class but I get an exception Could not cast or convert from `System.Int64` to Model class

// Here is my model class

```
public class Model
{
  public long id { get; set; }
  public string name { get; set; }
  public long type { get; set; }
}

// Here is the call I am making.. FYI I am using RestSharp
response = HttpPost("URl");
var id =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model.id>(restResponse.Content); //How can I map just the Id.
```

My response from the API is a long data type ex: 658

Comment: Replace Model.id with long

Answer (score 1):

Replace `Model.id` by `long`.

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<long>
```

You can set it like this

```
Model model = new Model();
model.id = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<long>...
```

Comment: okay but how do I set it or map it the the c# property id

Answer (score 0):

You may adapt this example to your model.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
  string url = string.Format("your-api-url");
  var response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;

  string responseAsString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourModel>(responseAsString);
}

public class YourModel
{
   [JsonProperty("confirmed")]
   public ValueModel Confirmed { get; set; }
   [JsonProperty("recovered")]
   public ValueModel Recovered { get; set; }
   [JsonProperty("values")]
   public ValueModel Values { get; set; }
}

public class ValueModel
{
   [JsonProperty("value")]
   public int Value { get; set; }
}
```